# How to increase Detail band height dynamically

Tags: jasper-reports

My requirement is to increase the Detail band height dynamically when the text field has more data. Are there any settings to increase to it?
 I am using one *textField* in the Detail band when it has more information (words), it is displaying only some information.

i.e the words are being cut off. Depending on the detail *band height* the words are displaying. I would like to **increase** the *band height dynamically* when the *text field* has more data.

Answer (score 33):

First select your field and set following properties (**third** one is most important):

1. Position type: `float`
2. `Stretch` type: relative to tallest object
3. `Stretch` with overflow: `true` (checked)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the text field and surround object to `Position Type` `Float` in the object's properties.

This should let the report expand as the text field grows.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Report level properties. Advanced - Set the Column count and then Print order as Horizontal

Answer (score 0):

@Ehtisham's answer is right. But in newer version of Jaspersoft Studio there is no `Stretch with overflow` property. You have to select the overflow textfield and in the Properties, in `Text Adjust` select `StretchHeight`

1. Position type: float
2. Stretch type: relative to tallest object
3. Select Text Field and then in `Text Adjust` select `StretchHeight`

In the source it will look like this

```
<textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="29" y="0" width="501" height="50" uuid="220d14f8-7cee-4315-9cf7-647b7c480735"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```