# Jasper Reports: xls format cuts strings

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have following resource:
my.report.title = Important Report

I have following piece of jrxml source:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="120" y="64" width="60" height="14" backcolor="#DCDCDC" uuid="f3ae3e13-2dd3-4420-b96f-6b68c541ee98">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
    </box>
    <textElement>
        <font isBold="true"/>
        <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{my.report.title}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

What I see in the `.xls` output is that my title was cut to one word **Important** instead of **Important Report**.

How to fix it? Do we have solutions apart of expanding cell in `.jrxml`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Make an excel autofit generated by jxl.jar and jasperReports.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388033/how-to-make-an-excel-autofit-generated-by-jxl-jar-and-jasperreports-jar) & [How to increase Detail band height dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2544746/876298) & [Stretch a row if data overflows in jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1205410/876298) & [JasperReports text field stretching - can stretch height be limited?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8443842/876298)

Comment: I think this link from Alex has what you may be looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388033/how-to-make-an-excel-autofit-generated-by-jxl-jar-and-jasperreports-jar